# move_uploaded_file does not work in PHP

Tags: php, html, file-upload, permissions

I'm having some problems with the move_upload_file function. I always get "Upload not valid" message. Here the php and html code. Can you guys see some errors? 
The upload directory is writable as you can see from the picture below.

[ls -l command output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9BRd.png)
[ls -l command output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwZkq.png)

Here the PHP

```
        $tmp_dir = $_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'];
        $imgSize = $_FILES['avatar']['size'];
        $upload_dir = '../../img/useravatar/';
        $userpic = hash("md5", time() . $imgFile) . "." . $imgExt;
        if ($imgSize < 5000000) {
            if (!is_writable($upload_dir))
                die("Permission denied when uploading file");
            if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir, $upload_dir . $userpic)) {
                //success
                die("Success");
            }else{
                //fail
                die("Upload not valid");
            }
        }else{
            redirect("../mainPages/signup.php", "Too large");
        }
```

Here the HTML

```
      <form class="form-signup" enctype="multipart/form-data"action="../submitPages/newUser.php" method = "post">
         <div class="form-group">
           <label for="avatar">Choose avatar</label>
           <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="avatar" accept="image/*" id="avatar">
         </div>
         <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
      <form>
```

Here the var_dump($_FILES)

```
 array (size=1)
  'avatar' => 
    array (size=5)
     'name' => string 'IMG_20160725_134910.jpg' (length=23)
     'type' => string '' (length=0)
     'tmp_name' => string '' (length=0)
     'error' => int 1
     'size' => int 0
```

Here the ls -l commands

```
drwxrwxrwx 3 nicola nicola 4096 Jan 27 02:31 img
drwxrwxrwx 2 nicola nicola    4096 Jan 15 03:37 useravatar
```

EDIT: It works with .png img.

Comment: First post commands output as text, not screenshots.

Comment: And this code example is complete? You are not altering the value of `$tmp_dir` in anyway before you use it in `move_uploaded_file`?

Comment: Actually, please do a `print_r($_FILES);` at the top of your php and return here with the result.

Comment: @IncredibleHat Hi guys, thanks for answering, I edited the original post with what you did ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` as an attribute to your `<form>` to send pictures correctly (you must add this when sending any `<input type="file">` items).

So your `<form>` should look like something like this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="path/to/PHPfile.php">
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="avatar">Choose avatar</label>
       <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="avatar" accept="image/*" id="avatar">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

If after setting the proper encoding type it still doesn't work try checking if the folder you are specifying exists in that path (correct might be `./../img/useravatar/` instead of `../../img/useravatar/`, etc.).

```
if(!file_exists("../../img/useravatar/")) echo 'no such directory';
```

---

**EDIT:**

Now that you posted the `var_dump($_FILES)` the error is evident. The image you are uploading exceeds the maximum size limit defined in php.ini.

> PHP returns an appropriate error code along with the file array. The error code can be found in the error segment of the file array that is created during the file upload by PHP. In other words, the error might be found in `$_FILES['userfile']['error']`.
>
> **UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE** Value: **1**; The uploaded file exceeds the `upload_max_filesize` directive in php.ini.

more on error codes here: [php.net/file-upload-errors](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

To set the values properly in php.ini you need to set the following fields:

```
memory_limit = 32M             // size of post_max_size or greater        
// this is the size of the whole POST
post_max_size = 32M            // should be greater than upload_max_filesize
// this is max size per uploaded file
upload_max_filesize = 24M
```

---

Alternatively, these settings can also be applied in `.htaccess`:

```
# this should be added at the bottom of the .htaccess file
php_value memory_limit 32M
php_value post_max_size 32M
php_value upload_max_filesize 24M
```

Comment: Hi Ivan86, I edited the original post with the full html code. As you can see, even with "enctype="multipart/form-data", it still does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: @palnic I edited, it seems like your image is too big. Try with a smaller one or set the `upload_max_filesize` to a higher value in php.ini.

Comment: Thanks man that is interesting. Maybe it could be smart to do a switch-case on ($_FILES['userfile']['error']) in the validation process. What you think? Anyway in my htaccess file I have the following strings: file_uploads = On
post_max_size = 15M
upload_max_filesize = 10M                                                                       The jpg image was 3,5MB so why?

Comment: That's weird. I got some additional information to share so I will edit again.

Comment: @palnic Check to see if setting the values like above solves your problem. If it doesn't, check to see if you have image limits written in `.htaccess`. Possibly in the `.htaccess` file that is in your `root` folder.

Comment: @palnic and yes, you could use a `switch-case` to check `$_FILES['userfile']['error']` for upload errors, where the value of `0` means no error.